# How to make a raw query on content://sms

Tags: android

I want to do a select distinct on content://sms
in order to do that I need to know how to open the content://sms as a database and make on it raw query.

Currently I am using normal query via contentResolver like this:

```
  ContentResolver mContectResolver = context.getContentResolver();
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
  String[] mProjection = {
        "address",
        "person",
        "body",
        "seen"
  };
  Cursor cursor = mContectResolver.query(uri, mProjection, null, null, null);
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to this question is:

You can't make a raw query on Android internal database like content://sms/ unless you have root privileges to open this database.

Natively Android blocks this database and has a special tool to open it with limited privileges and this tool is called ContentResolver.

May become handy to know information:
If you want to search for this database it will be in /data/data/databases folder. Search for it from rooted phone or Android virtual device.